# Angular-CLI Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-cli

I get this error when serving Angular 2 application on browser:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at eval (eval at t.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:1:15)
at eval (<anonymous>)
at t.exports (addScript.js:9)
at Object.355 (parsley.js?a34d:1)
at r (bootstrap 8987729…:52)
at Object.688 (scripts.f16ed82….bundle.js:155)
at r (bootstrap 8987729…:52)
at window.webpackJsonp (bootstrap 8987729…:23)
at scripts.f16ed82….bundle.js:1
```

Below you have my configuration:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "prod": "ng build -prod",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23",
    "animate.css": "3.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "2.1.4",
    "metismenu": "^2.5.0",
    "flexslider": "2.6.3",
    "jquery.easing": "1.4.1",
    "magnific-popup": "1.1.0",
    "jquery-sticky": "1.0.4",
    "owl.carousel": "2.2.0",
    "parsley": "0.1.0",
    "themify-icons": "1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.2.30",
    "@types/node": "6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.18",
    "codelyzer": "1.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.3"
  }
}
```

angular-cli.json

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "my-app"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "../webapp",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
        "../node_modules/flexslider/flexslider.css",
        "../node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css",
        "../node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css",
        "../node_modules/magnific-popup/dist/magnific-popup.css",
        "assets/styles/styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/jquery.easing/jquery.easing.js",
        "../node_modules/jquery-sticky/jquery.sticky.js",
        "../node_modules/flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js",
        "../node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js",
        "../node_modules/magnific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js",
        "../node_modules/parsley/bench/parsley.js",
        "assets/js/app.js",
        "../node_modules/metismenu/dist/metisMenu.js",
        "../src/vendor/pace/pace.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Any idea what could cause this error?**
This is an angular 2 application built with angular cli directly inside maven, using frontend-maven-plugin inside a spring boot app. But the angular 2 application could be also built separately using only node, npm and ng.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided your karma.conf.js in question description.
Please check it must include:-

```
 frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs']
```

in config set section.

Comment: Tried it. Still doesn't work. I also noticed that if I add a component that contains either the footer or section html tag, it will still build, but in the browser the application will not load and will throw this error:

**EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**